# RestFB - Viewing login dialog

Tags: facebook, playframework, restfb

I'm trying to make Facebook log in dialog appear on a web page.

According to RestFB, to get the log in dialog, I have to write this code:

```
ScopeBuilder scopeBuilder = new ScopeBuilder();
scopeBuilder.addPermission(UserDataPermissions.USER_STATUS);
scopeBuilder.addPermission(UserDataPermissions.USER_ABOUT_ME);          


FacebookClient client = new DefaultFacebookClient(Version.VERSION_2_2);
String loginDialogUrlString = client.getLoginDialogUrl(appId, redirectUrl,     scopeBuilder);
```

However, when I write this code on a certain java document, I don't get any log in dialog on the web page.

How can I link this code to show on a html web page as a log in dialog??

The project I'm working on contains basic MVC architecture (play framework).

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you have a valid appId and redirectUrl specified for your 'getLoginDialogUrl'? Double check against your FB app settings: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[APP_ID]/settings/.

Answer (score 1):

You should let the user open the `loginDialogUrlString` in a browser window and after the login process at Facebook the user is redirected to your page, or at least to the given `redirectUrl`.

Log the loginDialogUrlString somewhere and put it manually in the browser, this should open the login dialog. If not check your settings and open an issue at RestFB (Github).